# Running MongoDB, not recognizing mongod.exe or mongo.exe

Tags: mongodb

I have been running MongoDB fine on my system, ran it 2 days ago. Now I am not able to access my file folders at all. When I type DIR, I see the files but when I try to access them through command line I get ObjectNotFound.

```
 PS C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin> cd ./mongo.exe
 cd : Cannot find path './mongo.exe' because it does not exist.
 At line:1 char:1
 + cd ./mongo.exe
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./mongo.exe:String) [Set- 
Location], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: Why `cd ./mongo.exe` ? Just `mongo` does not do it?

Comment: neither, but I removed the cd....and it works.